# Using stringByReplacingCharactersInRange in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to use UITextFieldDelegate in Swift/Xcode6 and I'm struggling with the way I'm supposed to use stringByReplacingCharactersInRange. The compiler error is 'Cannot convert the expression's type 'String' to type '$T8'.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField!, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String!) -> Bool
{
    let s = textField.text.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range:range, withString:string)
    if countElements(s) > 0 {

    } else {

    }
    return true
}
```

Update for Xcode 6 Beta 5: The thing is shouldChangeCharactersInRange gives an NSRange object and we'd need a Swift Range object for stringByReplacingCharactersInRange. Can this still be considered a bug as I don't see why we should still be dealing with NS* objects? The String argument of the delegate method is anyway of a Swift type.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here's how to calculate the resulting string in various Swift versions.

Note that all methods use `-[NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]` in exactly the same way, just differing in syntax.

This is the preferred way to calculate the resulting string. Converting to a Swift `Range` and use that on a Swift `String` is error prone. Johan's answer for example is incorrect in a couple of ways when operating on non-ASCII strings.

#### Swift 3:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let result = (textField.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) ?? string
    // ... do something with `result`
}
```

#### Swift 2.1:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let result = (textField.text as NSString?)?.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
    // ... do something with `result`
}
```

#### Swift 1 (only left here for reference):

```
let result = textField.text.bridgeToObjectiveC().stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString:string)
```

Comment: String has this method. See my comment.

Comment: @TomášLinhart Where does `String` declare this method? I can't find it in the Swift module.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe I don't know. But see my post and run in it in the playground and you will see it works.

Comment: iOS8 beta 5 compiler says: 'String' does not have a member names 'bridgeToObjectiveC'

Comment: At least as of Beta 5 this is no longer the correct answer.

Comment: Use "textField.text as NSString" cast instead.

Answer (score 17):

I created an extension to `NSRange` the converted to `Range<String.Index>`

```
extension NSRange {
    func toRange(string: String) -> Range<String.Index> {
        let startIndex = advance(string.startIndex, location)
        let endIndex = advance(startIndex, length)
        return startIndex..<endIndex
    }
}
```

So I can create the String like this

```
let text = textField.text
let newText = text.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range.toRange(text), withString: string)
```

in Swift 2.1 the extension looks like:

```
extension NSRange {
    func toRange(string: String) -> Range<String.Index> {
        let startIndex = string.startIndex.advancedBy(location)
        let endIndex = startIndex.advancedBy(length)
        return startIndex..<endIndex
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely the Swift-most answer in there. But you can avoid the `self`s :)

Comment: @DavideDeFranceschi I added the `self`s for clarity. But you are correct, they are not needed

Comment: That's a nice approach, but it breaks when you use unicode characters, such as emoji. Give it a try

Comment: In Swift 2, you'd use `advancedBy`: `let startIndex = string.startIndex.advancedBy(location); let endIndex = startIndex.advancedBy(length)`

Comment: shouldn't the end index be advanced by `location + length` ?

Comment: There seems to be an error in the Swift 2.1 example of this solution. I think`let endIndex = string.startIndex.advancedBy(length)` should be `let endIndex = startIndex.advancedBy(length)`

Comment: @Joham correct
    let endIIndex = startIndex.advancedBy(length)

Comment: The approach in this answer is incorrect. You are using an NSString's character index for an indices on a Swift string's chracter view. These are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 15):

The simplest solution I have found is using `as NSString` - that enables us to use `NSRange`.

```
var textField : UITextField = UITextField()
textField.text = "this is a test"

let nsRange : NSRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: 4)

let replaced = (textField.text as NSString)
               .stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(nsRange, withString: "that");

NSLog("Replaced: %@", replaced); //prints "that is a test"
```

Answer (score 7):

```
let newString = (textField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
```

bridgeToObjectiveC can be removed in coming updates

Comment: Short and sweet. As of swift2, textField.text needs force unwrapped: let newString = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

Answer (score 6):

Nothing worked for me except the following: (FYI I'm using **Xcode7.0 GM**, **Swift 2.0**, **iOS9GM**)

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let currentText = textField.text ?? ""
    let prospectiveText = (currentText as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
    print("prospectiveText", prospectiveText)
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As of Swift 4, this is a little simpler, like Alexander Volkov's answer, but without the extension.

```
   func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let revisedText: String
        if let text = textField.text, let swiftRange = Range(range, in: text) {
            revisedText = text.replacingCharacters(in: swiftRange, with: string)
        } else {
            revisedText = string
        }
        // Do something with the text and return boolean.
   }
```

Comment: Change `let` to `var` to make `revisedText` mutable.

Answer (score 2):

This is a cross-post from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044851/how-do-you-use-string-substringwithrange-or-how-do-ranges-work-in-swift), but without a way to make a `Range<String.Index>` the Swift-native `String.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange()` is pretty useless. So, here's a function to generate a `Range<String.Index>`:

```
func RangeMake(#start:Int, #end:Int) -> Range<String.Index> {
    assert(start <= end, "start must be less than or equal to end")
    func rep(str: String, count: Int) -> String {
        var result = ""
        for i in 0..count {
            result += str
        }
        return result
    }
    let length = end - start
    let padding = rep(" ", start)
    let dashes = rep("-", length)
    let search = padding + dashes
    return search.rangeOfString(dashes, options: nil, range: Range(start: search.startIndex, end: search.endIndex), locale: NSLocale.systemLocale())
}

let sourceString = "Call me Ishmael."
let range = RangeMake(start: 8, end: 15)    
let name = sourceString.substringWithRange(range)
// name = "Ishmael"
```

Answer (score 2):

**Working & tested**

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let newString = NSString(string: textField.text!).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

    print(newString)

      return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating String.Index is cumbersome.

```
let string = "hello"
let range = string.startIndex .. string.startIndex.succ().succ()
let result = string.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: "si")
```

Comment: I would post this as a bug. There should be a better way to create ranges of strings. Or maybe I just can't find it.

Comment: Feel free to report it. I also didn't find a better way.

Comment: I agree, my gut feeling was that this is a bug. For example stringByAppendingString works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

for iOS 8.3 use following code

```
 func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    if textField.isEqual(<textField whose value to be copied>)
    {
        <TextField to be updated>.text = (textField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Swift 2.0, the answer from Durul must be changed because characters.count must be used instead of count().

The following must be done.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let length = textField.text!.characters.count - range.length + string.characters.count
    if length > 0 {
        submitButton.enabled = true
    } else {
        submitButton.enabled = false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var submitButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let length = count(textField.text) - range.length + count(string)
        if length > 0 {
            submitButton.enabled = true
        } else {
            submitButton.enabled = false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4:**

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    var text = textField.text ?? ""
    text.replaceSubrange(range.toRange(string: text), with: string)
    ...
    return true
}

extension NSRange {

    /// Convert to Range for given string
    ///
    /// - Parameter string: the string
    /// - Returns: range
    func toRange(string: String) -> Range<String.Index> {
        let range = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: self.lowerBound)..<string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: self.upperBound)
        return range
    }
}
```

Comment: When I delete one char I obtain a `Fatal error: Can't advance past endIndex`

Comment: @Maximelc The suggested approach is correct. Provide your code.