# Type 'String.Index' does not conform protocol 'IntegerLiteralConvertible'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

With Beta 3 all worked fine, now I get a strange error, and I have no clue how to fix it. Tried all the solutions for similiar problems.

Here is my code:

```
if !name.isEmpty {
        var splitted: [String] = name.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

        for curPart in splitted {
            if !curPart.isEmpty {
                acronym += curPart.substringToIndex(1) //Error
            }
        }
        if (acronym as NSString).length > 2 {
            acronym = acronym.substringToIndex(2) //Error
        }
    }
```

Both marked lines gave me the same error:

> Type 'String.Index' does not conform protocol 'IntegerLiteralConvertible'

Can someone help me? Or is Beta 4 bugged?
Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In beta 4, Swift's String.Index handling changed yet again -- you now can't supply an `Int` when a `String.Index` is expected. The way to handle it is by creating the `String.Index` you need using the `advance` method:

```
if !name.isEmpty {
    var splitted: [String] = name.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

    for curPart in splitted {
        if !curPart.isEmpty {
            acronym += curPart.substringToIndex(advance(curPart.startIndex, 1))
        }
    }
    if countElements(acronym) > 2 {
        acronym = acronym.substringToIndex(advance(acronym.startIndex, 2))
    }
}
```

This is all based on making sure Unicode strings are handled properly - since different Unicode characters can have different sizes, pure integer indexing would hide the fact that Strings aren't random access.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It compiles and seem to work! Thanks. I also think this will change before swift 1.0

Comment: "This is all based on making sure Unicode strings are handled properly - since different Unicode characters can have different sizes, pure integer indexing would hide the fact that Strings aren't random access.". I thought swift getas around that by using  the `Charcater` type (instead of, e.g. bytes) which is exactly one unicode character, and swift `String`s could be thought of as arrays of such? What stands in the way of accessing the n-th (unicode) character of the string?

Comment: No, each `Character` is a single *visible* character in the string, which can be made up of one, two, or many code points. For example, ‍‍‍ is seven, I think.

Comment: In case you're looking for an extension that does use the Int to get all the substrings you may want, try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044851/how-do-you-use-string-substringwithrange-or-how-do-ranges-work-in-swift/39742687#39742687

Comment: "What stands in the way of accessing the n-th (unicode) character of the string?" -- Swift's philosophy is that you should feel the runtime cost of Unicode string processing while writing your code. Expensive operations are painful to write.

Answer (score 12):

Swift's notion of string components and iteration has changed in Beta 4. From [the guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-XID_408), we see:

> Every instance of Swift’s Character type represents a single extended grapheme cluster. An extended grapheme cluster is a sequence of one or more Unicode scalars that (when combined) produce a single human-readable character.

This has some interesting side effects:

```
let str1 = "abc"
let str2 = "\u{20DD}def"

countElements(str1)      // 3 
countElements(str2)      // 4
countElements(str1+str2) // 6 ≠ 3+4 !!!
```

That's because the `c` and `\u{20DD}` combine to form   c⃝. Also notice that we're using `countElements`. In order to figure out the length of the string, Swift actually has to *iterate through the whole string* and figure out where the actual grapheme divisions are, so it takes O(n) time.

We can also see the effect on different encodings:

```
Array((str1+str2).utf8)  // [97, 98, 99, 226, 131, 157, 100, 101, 102]
Array((str1+str2).utf16) // [97, 98, 99, 8413, 100, 101, 102]
```

Another issue, as your error says, is that `String`'s `IndexType` is no longer convertible from an integer literal: you can't perform random access on the string by specifying an offset. Instead, you can use `startIndex` and `advance` to move forward some distance in the string, for example `str[str.startIndex]` or `str[advance(str.startIndex, distance)]`.

Or you can define your own helper functions in the meantime:

```
func at<C: Collection>(c: C, i: C.IndexType.DistanceType) -> C.GeneratorType.Element {
    return c[advance(c.startIndex, i)]
}

func take<C: protocol<Collection, Sliceable>>(c: C, n: C.IndexType.DistanceType) -> C.SliceType {
    return c[c.startIndex..<advance(c.startIndex, n)]
}

at(str1+str2, 3)   // d

take(str1+str2, 2) // ab
```

Obviously there are some improvements that could (and probably will) be made in future updates. You may want to [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) with your concerns. In the long run, supporting grapheme clusters correctly was probably a good decision, but it makes string access a little more painful in the meantime.

Comment: Ok, now I know whats going on under the hood :D Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**For Swift 2.0**

Using the example above:

```
curPart.substringToIndex(curPart.startIndex.advancedBy(1))
```