# How to compare ranges in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm not sure if it's a bug in XCode or I didn't understand ranges in Swift. Here is some code to show how range works:

```
let range = 0..<5
contains(range, 0) // true
contains(range, 5) // false
range.startIndex == 0 // true
range.endIndex == 5 // true

let str = "Hello, playground"
str.rangeOfString("Hello")! // 0..<5
```

Great! Now let's use it real code:

```
let str = "Hello, playground"
if let range = str.rangeOfString("Hello") {
    if range.startIndex == 0 {
        print("str starts with 'Hello'")
    }
}
```

I'm getting following error in line that reads `if range.startIndex == 0 {`

> Cannot invoke '==' with an argument lis of type (String.index,
>   IntegerLiteralConvertible)'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`rangeOfString` actually returns a range of `String.Index`s and not `Int`s; the two aren't comparable (even though the playground shows the range as `0..<5`). You can read about the reasons for that in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24880604/3300036).

If you want your example to work then, instead of comparing `range.startIndex` with `0`, you should compare it with `str.startIndex`:

```
let str = "Hello, playground"
if let range = str.rangeOfString("Hello") {
    if range.startIndex == str.startIndex {
        print("str starts with 'Hello'")
    }
}
```

If you need to compare to the range's `startIndex` with, say, the second character index in the string, then you can use the [`advance`](http://swifter.natecook.com/func/advance/) function to increment `str.startIndex` by `1` and compare `range.startIndex` to that:

```
let str = "Hello, playground"
if let range = str.rangeOfString("e") {
    if range.startIndex == advance(str.startIndex, 1) {
        print("str's 2nd character is 'e'")
    }
}
```

If you need to know the length of the range, then you can use the [`distance`](http://swifter.natecook.com/func/distance/) function:

```
let str = "Hello, playground"
if let range = str.rangeOfString("play") {
    let length = distance(range.startIndex, range.endIndex)
    print("found a range \(length) characters long")
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. I assume all this ceremony is for better Unicode support. For example it supports crazy characters like `"ﷺ"`. I just tried it

Comment: Exactly, it's like this for Unicode support. Basically it lets you jump around one character at a time, even if the characters are multi-byte.

Comment: @Mohsen It's is not a crazy character but a sentence in arabic that says : « Peace upon him » (صلى الله عليه وآله وسلم) muslims use to praise the Prophet. As a convenience (as it is often used) this sentence exists as a one-packed ligature glyph (as many others). Hope it uncovers a mystery :-)

Answer (score 15):

The ~= operator in Swift

Sometimes, we have to check if a number is between a range, and as usual, we do something like :

Check if number is between 0 and 100 include

```
if number >=0 && number <= 100 {  
   // TODO:
}
```

It works, but we can do better and swiftier. The Swift Standard library have an ~= operator, so we can do instead :

```
if 0...100 ~= number {  
   // TODO:
 }
```