# Type 'String.Index' does not conform protocol '_Strideable'

Tags: swift

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880604/type-string-index-does-not-conform-protocol-integerliteralconvertible) thread but it seems have another problem. This code:

```
if value.range(of: String(formatter.minusSign))?.count > 0 {
    //STH
}
```

(where `formatter` is `NumberFormatter` object and `value` is `String`) produce this error in Swift:

> Type 'String.Index' does not conform to protocol '_Strideable'

How to solve it?

Comment: What would the expected result for `count` be? What about a simple `if value.contains(formatter.minusSign)` ?

Comment: I am refactoring old objective-c code 1:1 and there was `if (!([value rangeOfString: [_formatter minusSign]].length > 0)){`

Comment: Swift Range and NSRange are quite different.

Comment: @vadian Hence my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if the range is not `nil`

```
if value.range(of: formatter.minusSign) != nil {
    //STH
}
```

or – preferable if you want to use the range – optional bindings

```
if let range = value.range(of: formatter.minusSign) {
    // do somthing with the range
}
```

or simply

```
if value.contains(formatter.minusSign) {
    //STH
}
```

Comment: `String(...)` isn't needed.

Comment: @MartinR Right. *Don't adopt bad habits* 

Comment: I have a range that the compiler tells me is not optional but I get that same error "Type 'String.Index' does not conform to protocol '_Strideable'".