# How to use substringToIndex in Swift?

Tags: swift, substring

I get compiler error at this line:

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor.UUIDString.substringToIndex(8)
```

*Type 'String.Index' does not conform to protocol 'IntegerLiteralConvertible'*

My intention is to get the substring, but how?

Comment: more elegant solution **(** UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor.UUIDString **as NSString)**.substringToIndex(8) - need convert type

Answer (score 185, accepted):

In Swift, `String` indexing respects grapheme clusters, and an `IndexType` is not an `Int`. You have two choices - cast the string (your UUID) to an NSString, and use it as "before", or create an index to the nth character.

Both are illustrated below :

However, the method has changed radically between versions of Swift. Read down for later versions...

**Swift 1**

```
let s: String = "Stack Overflow"
let ss1: String = (s as NSString).substringToIndex(5) // "Stack"
//let ss2: String = s.substringToIndex(5)// 5 is not a String.Index
let index: String.Index = advance(s.startIndex, 5)
let ss2:String = s.substringToIndex(index) // "Stack"
```

CMD-Click on `substringToIndex` confusingly takes you to the `NSString` definition, however CMD-Click on `String` and you will find the following:

```
extension String : Collection {
    struct Index : BidirectionalIndex, Reflectable {
        func successor() -> String.Index
        func predecessor() -> String.Index
        func getMirror() -> Mirror
    }
    var startIndex: String.Index { get }
    var endIndex: String.Index { get }
    subscript (i: String.Index) -> Character { get }
    func generate() -> IndexingGenerator<String>
}
```

**Swift 2**
As commentator @DanielGalasko points out `advance` has now changed...

```
let s: String = "Stack Overflow"
let ss1: String = (s as NSString).substringToIndex(5) // "Stack"
//let ss2: String = s.substringToIndex(5)// 5 is not a String.Index
let index: String.Index = s.startIndex.advancedBy(5) // Swift 2
let ss2:String = s.substringToIndex(index) // "Stack"
```

**Swift 3**
In Swift 3, it's changed again:

```
let s: String = "Stack Overflow"
let ss1: String = (s as NSString).substring(to: 5) // "Stack"
let index: String.Index = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)
var ss2: String = s.substring(to: index) // "Stack"
```

**Swift 4**
In Swift 4, yet another change:

```
let s: String = "Stack Overflow"
let ss1: String = (s as NSString).substring(to: 5) // "Stack"
let index: String.Index = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)
var ss3: Substring = s[..<index] // "Stack"
var ss4: String = String(s[..<index]) // "Stack"
```

Comment: In Swift 2 advance is no longer a global function but now a function on `Index`.  `s.startIndex.advanceBy(5)`

Comment: Doesn't work for Swift 2.1.  I got the msg: "value of type 'index'...has no member 'advancedBy'".

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee new syntax is `s.startIndex.advancedBy(1)`

Comment: Using `NSString` isn't really a Swift answer.

Comment: In case you want an extension for Swift 3 that gets the job done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044851/how-do-you-use-string-substringwithrange-or-how-do-ranges-work-in-swift/39742687#39742687

Comment: Note that this is only guaranteed to work on Apple platforms, since `NSString` is a Cocoa/Cocoa Touch type.

Comment: @benleggiero - did you read the answer? There are two methods given, one using Swift, one using NSString...

Comment: `s[...index]` actually returns `Stack ` (trailing space) - perhaps you meant `s[..<index]`?

Comment: @Tim - absolutely correct. <blushes>. Now corrected.