# Swift 4: 'substring(to:)' is deprecated

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I'm having trouble converting my Swift 3 code to Swift 4. I've managed to translate everything else in the app successfully, but am having trouble with a single line of code:

```
cleanURL = cleanURL.substring(to: cleanURL.index(before: cleanURL.endIndex))
```

The error I'm getting is this:

```
ViewController.swift:62:33: 'substring(to:)' is deprecated: Please use String slicing subscript with a 'partial range upto' operator.
```

Comment: are you sure it makes sense to be mutating a variable, rather than defining a new one? If the url is "clean" after taking off the last symbol, why is it called "cleanURL" even before then?

Comment: Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45562662/6541007). Seems to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 31):

Well, do what the error says, use the String slicing subscript ([`subscript(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/subscript(_:)-2so14)) with a 'partial range upto' operator (`..<`, [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/index/%27.._(_:_:)), where it's called a 'half open range', oddly enough):

```
let actuallyCleanURL = kindaCleanURL[..<kindaCleanURL.endIndex]
```

Note that this returns a `Substring`. If you need to do more slicing operations, do them on this substring. Once you're done, promote your to a `String` by running it through the `String` initializer (`String(mySubString)`), causing a copy of the memory to be made.

Comment: This doesn't return a String, but a String.SubSequence. You will need to convert it to a string with String(...) for it work like the OP intended.

Comment: @timgcarlson Good point