# 'substring(to:)' is deprecated: Please use String slicing subscript with a 'partial range upto' operator

Tags: swift, substring, swift4

How can I update the following code to the new version of swift:

```
self.areaCodeLael.text! = localNumber.substring(to: localNumber.index(localNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 3))
```

I have tried following this post but I can't get it right 
[How can I use String slicing subscripts in Swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45562662/how-to-use-string-slicing-subscript-in-swift-4)

I adjusted my original code to `localNumber[..<3]` but I get:

> Cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'PartialRangeUpTo'

Comment: Update your question showing how you attempted to make use of the information in the linked question.

Comment: Unrelated but why are you putting the `!` operator just before the `=`? Get rid of that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would say `localNumber.prefix(3)` in this situation. Short and sweet.

Comment: I tried that but prefix is an unresolved identifier localNumber.String(prefix(3))

Comment: I got it to work, thank you for the suggestion String(localNumber.characters.prefix(3))

Comment: @user1079052 No, you want `String(localNumber.prefix(3))`.

Comment: I wrapped it in String(). Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The problem with your attempt to use `localNumber[..<3]` is that you can't pass an `Int` as the range. You need to pass a `String.Index`.

Your code needs to be:

```
let index = localNumber.index(localNumber.startIndex, offsetBy: 3)
self.areaCodeLael.text = localNumber[..<index]
```

Also note that you do not want the `!` operator after `text`.

Comment: I get "_Cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'PartialRangeUpTo<String.Index>'_"

Comment: Oh, I solve it by wrapping the subscript result with `String( … )`, like `String(localNumber[..<index])`