# How to use String subscript in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to convert Swift 3 code into Swift 4. But this error shows:

> "substring(from:)' is deprecated: Please use String slicing subscript
>   with a 'partial range from' operator."

my code is :

```
extension String {

    func substring(_ from: Int) -> String {
        return self.substring(from: self.characters.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: from))
    }

}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45562662/how-to-use-string-slicing-subscript-in-swift-4

Comment: i already checked.... but still don't understand... can you please explain... @algrid

Comment: can you please explain @MoeAbdul-Hameed

Comment: @UdayBabariya Read this and you'll be fine. Let me know if you needed more details. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID555

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have:

```
extension String {

    func substring(_ from: Int) -> String {
        let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: from)
        return String(self[start ..< endIndex])
    }
}
```

In swift you can get a substring using slicing - a construction like this: `string[startIndex ..< endIndex]`. String index is a special type in swift so you can't use simple ints - you have to get proper indexes for instance calling `index(_,offsetBy:)` or using predefined `startIndex` and `endIndex`.