# Swift 4 'substring(from:)' is deprecated: Please use String slicing subscript with a 'partial range from' operator

Tags: swift, substring, deprecated, swift4

i've just converted my little app but i've found this error:
'substring(from:)' is deprecated: Please use String slicing subscript with a 'partial range from' operator

my code is:

```
    let dateObj = dateFormatterFrom.date(from: dateStringa)


    if dateObj != nil {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateFormatterTo.string(from:(dateObj!))
    } else {
        let index = thisRecord.pubDate.index(thisRecord.pubDate.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = thisRecord.pubDate.substring(from: index)
    }
```

Answer (score 48):

Follow the below example to fix this warning:
Supporting examples for Swift 3, 4 and 5.

```
let testStr = “Test Teja”

let finalStr = testStr.substring(to: index) // Swift 3
let finalStr = String(testStr[..<index]) // Swift 4

let finalStr = testStr.substring(from: index) // Swift 3
let finalStr = String(testStr[index...]) // Swift 4 

//Swift 3
let finalStr = testStr.substring(from: index(startIndex, offsetBy: 3)) 

//Swift 4 and 5
let reqIndex = testStr.index(testStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 3)
let finalStr = String(testStr[..<reqIndex])

//**Swift 5.1.3 - usage of index**

let myStr = "Test Teja == iOS"

let startBound1 = String.Index(utf16Offset: 13, in: myStr)
let finalStr1 = String(myStr[startBound1...])// "iOS"

let startBound2 = String.Index(utf16Offset: 5, in: myStr)
let finalStr2 = String(myStr[startBound2..<myStr.endIndex]) //"Teja == iOS"
```

Comment: @TejaKumarBethina Your 5.1.3 update is wrong. You should not use String `Index(utf16Offset:)` initializer to offset your index as most usage of it is wrong. Try `let myStr = "iOS"` `let startBound1 = String.Index(utf16Offset: 3, in: myStr)` `let finalStr1 = String(myStr[startBound1...])` //  would result in "iOS" instead of "iOS" and `let startBound2 = String.Index(utf16Offset: 5, in: myStr)` `let finalStr2 = String(myStr[startBound2..<myStr.endIndex])` // would result in "iOS" instead of "S"

Answer (score 16):

In place of `substring` use `suffix`. Use like below :

```
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(thisRecord.pubDate.suffix(from: index))
```

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
No work, say me:

Cannot assign value of type 'String.SubSequence' (aka 'Substring') to type 'String?'

Raf

Comment: This worked for me, I just replaced subString for suffix, then Xcode prompted me to make some code changes and it worked!.  The line now reads:                                return String(self.suffix(from: to))

Answer (score 12):

It means you should use the new partial range operator as your upperBound:

```
let str =  "Hello World !!!"
if let index = str.range(of: "Hello ")?.upperBound {
   let string = String(str[index...])  // "World !!!"
}
```

In your case

```
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(thisRecord.pubDate[index...]))
```

Answer (score 5):

In Swift 5, it is:

```
extension String {

    func index(from: Int) -> Index {
        return self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: from)
    }

    func substring(from: Int) -> String {
        let fromIndex = index(from: from)
        return String(self[fromIndex...])
    }

    func substring(to: Int) -> String {
        let toIndex = index(from: to)
        return String(self[..<toIndex])
    }

    func substring(with r: Range<Int>) -> String {
        let startIndex = index(from: r.lowerBound)
        let endIndex = index(from: r.upperBound)
        return String(self[startIndex..<endIndex])
    }
}
```

Comment: @Adrian note that when using the last method (range) it will unnecessarily offset both indices from the startIndex. `let endIndex = index(startIndex, offsetBy: r.count)` Note that this will offset only the range count from the local startIndex thats been already offset

Answer (score 4):

Most of my strings have A-Za-z and 0-9 content. No need for difficult
Index handling. This extension of String is based on the familiar LEFT / MID and RIGHT functions.

```
extension String {

    // LEFT
    // Returns the specified number of chars from the left of the string
    // let str = "Hello"
    // print(str.left(3))         // Hel
    func left(_ to: Int) -> String {
        return "\(self[..<self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: to)])"
    }

    // RIGHT
    // Returns the specified number of chars from the right of the string
    // let str = "Hello"
    // print(str.left(3))         // llo
    func right(_ from: Int) -> String {
        return "\(self[self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: self.length-from)...])"
    }

    // MID
    // Returns the specified number of chars from the startpoint of the string
    // let str = "Hello"
    // print(str.left(2,amount: 2))         // ll
    func mid(_ from: Int, amount: Int) -> String {
        let x = "\(self[self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: from)...])"
        return x.left(amount)
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this would crash if you pass an Int larger than the string count. Much easier to use Collection prefix method that wouldn't crash and return a Substring or initialise a new String with it before returning it `func left(_ to: Int) -> String {
        return String(prefix(to))
    }`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language/38215613#38215613

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to get substring with specific offset without upper bound do the following:

```
let index = thisRecord.pubDate.index(thisRecord.pubDate.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(thisRecord.pubDate[index...]
```

This way you create a new `String` object from your existing `String thisRecord.pubDate` taking anything from specified index to the end index of original `String`.

Answer (score 0):

```
str[..<index]
str[index...]
```

The code above is "partial range from"
Look at this [How can I use String slicing subscripts in Swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45562662/how-can-i-use-string-slicing-subscripts-in-swift-4)

Comment: AFAICT this syntax is now obsolete.