# 'substring(from:)' is deprecated: Please use String slicing subscript with a 'partial range from' operator. Swift 4 Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, swift4

I am converting my existing app from `Swift 3` to `Swift 4`. It is giving the error:

> 'substring(from:)' is deprecated: Please use String slicing subscript with a 'partial range from' operator.

and

> 'characters' is deprecated: Please use String or Substring directly

My `Swift 3` code is:

```
public convenience init?(hexString: String, alpha: Float) {
    var hex = hexString

    // Check for hash and remove the hash
    if hex.hasPrefix("#") {
        hex = hex.substring(from: hex.characters.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 1))
    }

    if (hex.range(of: "(^[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}$)|(^[0-9A-Fa-f]{3}$)", options: .regularExpression) != nil) {

        // Deal with 3 character Hex strings
        if hex.characters.count == 3 {
            let redHex   = hex.substring(to: hex.characters.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 1))
            let greenHex = hex.substring(with: (hex.characters.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 1) ..< hex.characters.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)))
            let blueHex  = hex.substring(from: hex.characters.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 2))

            hex = redHex + redHex + greenHex + greenHex + blueHex + blueHex
        }

        let redHex = hex.substring(to: hex.characters.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 2))
        let greenHex = hex.substring(with: (hex.characters.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 2) ..< hex.characters.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)))
        let blueHex = hex.substring(with: (hex.characters.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 4) ..< hex.characters.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 6)))

        var redInt:   CUnsignedInt = 0
        var greenInt: CUnsignedInt = 0
        var blueInt:  CUnsignedInt = 0

        Scanner(string: redHex).scanHexInt32(&redInt)
        Scanner(string: greenHex).scanHexInt32(&greenInt)
        Scanner(string: blueHex).scanHexInt32(&blueInt)

        self.init(red: CGFloat(redInt) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(greenInt) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(blueInt) / 255.0, alpha: CGFloat(alpha))
    }
    else {
        self.init()
        return nil
    }
}
```

How can I convert it to the **Swift 4**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'characters' is deprecated: Please use String or Substring directly

For this you can directly loop through string in swift 4 so there is no need to characters array.

And for

'substring(from:)' is deprecated: Please use String slicing subscript with a 'partial range from' operator.

Refer [How can I use String slicing subscripts in Swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45562662/how-can-i-use-string-slicing-subscripts-in-swift-4)