# How to change `substring` to its equivalent new version one in swift 4?

Tags: swift, xcode

I absolutely have no knowledge on xcode, swift, mac, etc, but I have to modify and a ready made project, just very little settings.

Everything is fine, but the following warning which I didn't understand how to fix it by googling and reading, because I don't know this language at all. I'll very thankful if someone kindly just write the equivalent swift 4 code for this:

WARNING:

```
'substring(from:)' is deprecated: Please use String slicing subscript with a 'partial range from' operator.
```

CODE:

```
hex = hex.substring(from: hex.characters.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 1))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46336932/swift-4-substringfrom-is-deprecated-please-use-string-slicing-subscript-wi?rq=1 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304522/substringfrom-is-deprecated-please-use-string-slicing-subscript-with-a-pa?rq=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning wants you to do this:

```
hex = String(hex[hex.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)...])
```

Notes:

- `hex.characters` is deprecated in Swift 4; use `hex` directly.
- `[index...]` is the *slicing subscript with a 'partial range from' operator*.  It says create a substring from `index` to the end of the string.  In this case, `index` is `hex.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)` which is just the index of the second character of the string.  Applying this slicing operator to `hex` creates a substring with all characters of `hex` from the second character to the end of the string.
- The only problem is that the slicing operator returns a substring of type `String.SubSequence` instead of `String`.  The `String()` is necessary to convert the `String.SubSequence` returned by the slicing operator back into a `String`.

---

**A Better Way**

All this line of code is doing is dropping the first character from the `String`.  In Swift 4, there is a better way:

```
hex = String(hex.dropFirst())
```

Notes:

- `dropFirst()` returns a `String.SubSequence` so it is necessary to use `String()` to convert that back into a `String`.
- This is actually better than the original code, because it won't crash when given an empty string `""`.

Comment: I'd highly appreciate if you also take a look at my other  question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48598578/how-to-fix-uialertview-was-deprecated-in-ios-9-0-uialertview-is-deprecated