# extract out substring but get compiler error

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, swift4.1

I have a string **"John+20"**, I would like to extract out "John", so, I tried following based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45562662/how-can-i-use-string-slicing-subscripts-in-swift-4):

```
// data contains value "John+20"
static func getName(fromString data: String?) {
  guard let myData = data else {
      return
  }

  let idx = myData.index(of: "+")
  //Compiler ERROR: Generic parameter 'Self' could not be inferred
  let name = String(myData[..<idx])
}
```

But I get the error I mentioned in code comment, why is that?

I am using Swift 4.1 in my iOS project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the index is an optional as well. Try :

```
// data contains value "John+20"
static func getName(fromString data: String?) {
  guard let myData = data else, let idx = myData.index(of: "+") {
      return
  }

  let name = String(myData[..<idx])
}
```