# substring(from:)' is deprecated. Use string slicing subscript with a 'partial range from' operator

Tags: swift4.2, xcode10.1

I have just coverted an app from *swift3* to *swift4.2* on Xcode 10.1

I am in the process of fixing some of the many errors that have appeared.
Apparently substring(from:)' is deprecated. Use string slicing subscript with a 'partial range from' operator

```
t_prefix_phone = contact_phone.substring(to:contact_phone.index(contact_phone.startIndex, offsetBy: 3))

t_phone = contact_phone.substring(from:contact_phone.index(contact_phone.endIndex, offsetBy: -7))
```

Could you please help me translate the code above to 4.2 in such a way that the results are still strings.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use String slicing subscripts in Swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45562662/how-can-i-use-string-slicing-subscripts-in-swift-4)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

swift 4 has prefix and suffix just for this:

```
    let contact_phone = "0123456789"
    let t_prefix_phone = String(contact_phone.prefix(3))
    let t_phone = String(contact_phone.suffix(7))
```