# Cannot subscript on Collection with a type of Self.Index

Tags: swift

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46634511) suggests how to extend the String class to enable subscripting. I thought it could be reused across my app by extending the `Collection` protocol instead. But this bit:

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/46634511
extension Collection {
    subscript(value: Int) -> Self.SubSequence {
            self[index(at: value)]
    }

    private func index(at offset: Int) -> Self.Index {
            index(startIndex, offsetBy: offset)
    }
}
```

cannot be compiled, because:

```
test.swift:3:7: error: cannot subscript a value of type 'Self' with an argument of type 'Self.Index'
                self[index(at: value)]
                    ^
test.swift:3:7: note: overloads for 'subscript' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: ((UnboundedRange_) -> ()), (Int), (Range<Self.Index>)
                self[index(at: value)]
                    ^
```

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/1641358-subscript), Collection already lets you subscript by index, but clearly the compiler doesn't recognize it.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the wrong return type for the subscript. It should be `Self.Element`, not `Self.SubSequence`:

```
subscript(value: Int) -> Self.Element {
    self[index(at: value)]
}
```

Presuambly, the compiler finds that there is a [subscript that returns a `Self.SubSequence`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/2963660-subscript) (the return type apparently takes priority in overload resolution here), and notices that it doesn't accept a `Self.Index`, hence the error.

A more helpful compiler would probably output an error message like "cannot convert return expression of type `Self.Element` to return type `Self.SubSequence`".