# substring(with:)' is deprecated: Please use String slicing subscript

Tags: swift

I'm getting this warning for the `return substring` line.  What is the better alternative?

```
///Returns an empty string when there is no path.
internal var path: String {
    if let match = range(of: "(?<=')[^']+", options: .regularExpression) {
        return substring(with: match)
    }
    return ""
}
```

Comment: @vadian, no it does not really, `substring(with:)` is a different method from `substring(of:)`.   I wish you had commented and we could have talked about this.

Comment: It does. Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45562662/how-can-i-use-string-slicing-subscripts-in-swift-4/46617119#46617119) in the duplicate. It covers `substring(from:`, `substring(to:` and `substring(with:`

Comment: Okay. Thank you.