# Convert Range<Int> to Range<String.Index>

Tags: ios, string, swift, range, nsrange

The below function given a `NSString`, removes the HTML tags from that string and returns the result also as a `NSString`.

```
private func removeHTMLTags(source: NSString) -> NSString {
    var range = NSMakeRange(0, 0)
    let HTMLTags = "<[^>]*>"
    var sourceString = source

    while sourceString.rangeOfString(HTMLTags, options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch).location != NSNotFound {
        range = sourceString.rangeOfString(HTMLTags, options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch)
        sourceString = sourceString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: "")
    }
    return sourceString;
}
```

I'm trying to rewrite this in pure Swift. I'm facing a issue with the `Range` type in Swift.

In the original code function, `range` variable is declared of type `NSRange`. In my version I cannot do that because the line `sourceString.rangeOfString(HTMLTags, options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch)` inside the while loop returns the type `Range<String.Index>` and it would give me the error **Cannot convert the expression's type '()' to type 'NSRange'**.

So I declared the variable like this `var range = Range(start: 0, end: 0)` but now I get a couple of new errors.

**Cannot convert the expression's type '()' to type 'Range'** error at the line

```
range = sourceString.rangeOfString(HTMLTags, options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch)
```

And **'Int' is not identical to 'String.Index'** at the line

```
sourceString = sourceString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: "")
```

I searched for a solution to this and came across this [post](http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/152335/Swift-Convert-Range-Int--to-Range-String). Then I changed the `range` variable declaration to this.

```
var range = Range<String.Index>(start: 0, end: 0)
```

But I get this new error now! **Extra argument 'end' in call**

I can't figure out a way to resolve this. Can anyone help please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Swift `String` method `rangeOfString()` returns an optional `Range?` which
does not have a `location` property but can be checked with  conditional binding (`if let`).

And if you replace the `NSString` method `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange()`
by the Swift `String` method `replaceRange()` (or in this case
simply by `removeRange()`) then you can work purely with `Range<Swift.Index>`
without converting it to `NSRange` or `Range<Int>`.

```
func removeHTMLTags(source : String) -> String {

    var sourceString = source
    let HTMLTags = "<[^>]*>"

    while let range = sourceString.rangeOfString(HTMLTags, options: .RegularExpressionSearch) {
        sourceString.removeRange(range)
    }

    return sourceString;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Huge thanks as always. I need to familiarize myself with this conditional binding more.

Comment: Besides this workaround, is there a way to create a `String.Index` from an `Int`?

Comment: @Rivera: Yes, with `advance()`, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044851/how-do-you-use-string-substringwithrange-or-how-do-ranges-work-in-swift. – But it depends on what you really want to do, the problem is that NSString and Swift strings count characters differently.

Answer (score 4):

For people like me who really want to get a `Range<String.Index>`:

```
func convert(range: Range<Int>, string: String) -> Range<String.Index>
{
    return Range<String.Index>(start: advance(string.startIndex, range.startIndex),
                               end: advance(string.startIndex, range.endIndex))
}
```

You do need to reference the string where you'll be using the range.

Comment: In Swift 2, this is `return Range(start: string.startIndex.advancedBy(nsRange.location), end: string.startIndex.advancedBy(nsRange.location+nsRange.length))`

Comment: Not it is not, we're dealing with Range not NSRange

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 2, given `string: String` and `nsRange: NSRange`, this is

```
let range = Range(start: string.startIndex.advancedBy(nsRange.location),
    end: string.startIndex.advancedBy(nsRange.location+nsRange.length))
```

Answer (score 0):

Swiss-army steam shovel for `String` subscripting, `NSRange`, `Range<Int|String.Index>` conversions

```
import Foundation

func +<T: IntegerType>(lhs: String.Index, rhs: T) -> String.Index {
    var r = lhs
    var x = rhs
    while x > 0 { // advance() won't work because IntegerType and String.Index are incompatible 
        r = r.successor()
        x--
    }
    while x < 0 {
        r = r.predecessor()
        x++
    }
    return r
}

func -<T: IntegerType>(lhs: String.Index, rhs: T) -> String.Index {
    var r = lhs
    var x = rhs
    while x > 0 {
        r = r.predecessor()
        x--
    }
    while x < 0 {
        r = r.successor()
        x++
    }
    return r
}

extension NSRange {
    init(range: Range<Int>) {
        location = range.startIndex
        length = range.endIndex - range.startIndex
    }

    var range: Range<Int> { return Range<Int>(start: location, end: location + length) }
}

extension String {
    var nsrange: NSRange { return NSMakeRange(0, count(self)) }

    var range: Range<Int> { return Range<Int>(start: 0, end: count(self)) }

    subscript (index: Int) -> String {
        return self[index...index]
    }

    subscript (index: Int) -> Character {
        return self[index] as Character
    }

    subscript (range: Range<String.Index>) -> String {
        return substringWithRange(range)
    }

    subscript (range: NSRange) -> String {
        return self[toStringRange(range)]
    }

    // allows "abcd"[0...1] // "ab"
    subscript (range: Range<Int>) -> String {
        return self[toStringRange(range)]
    }

    func toStringRange(range: NSRange) -> Range<String.Index> {
        return toStringRange(range.range)
    }

    func toStringRange(range: Range<Int>) -> Range<String.Index> {
        let start = startIndex + max(range.startIndex, 0)
        let end = startIndex + min(range.endIndex, count(self))
        return Range<String.Index>(start: start, end: end)
    }
}
```

[Gist here](https://gist.github.com/steakknife/78daa13c6773dc23d73b)

Answer (score 0):

Convert `NSRange` to `Range<String.Index>` swift function

```
func rangeWithString(string : String, range : NSRange) -> Range<String.Index> {
    return string.startIndex.advancedBy(range.location) ..< string.startIndex.advancedBy(range.location+range.length)
}
```