# How to delete some words in string in Swift

Tags: swift, parsing

I'm working on swift. How to delete between 2 characters, for example from '[' to ']' and how to delete "glass" word from a string?

Comment: There's lots of techniques for scanning strings in [this NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/nsscanner/).

Comment: Because of my Reputation is not enough to ask my question in more than 2 lines, i had to shrink my question and you're absolutely right that its little bit hard to understand what i try to ask. Sorry about that :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function modified to allow multiple deletions. The first function handles a single deletion. The second function splits the sentence into different sentences one for each start-end group and then applies function 1 before concatenating to get the final result. I have not tested it exhaustively. the first function is protected for non-existent startString and/or endString.

Function deleteEnclosedString returns the string remaining after string enclosed within startString and endString (inclusive) is deleted.

```
    import UIKit
    import Foundation


    var str = "Hello, [play]ground [again]hi everybody [again]"


func deleteEnclosedString (s: String, s1:String, s2: String) -> String {
    var returnedString = s
    var x = s.componentsSeparatedByString(s1)
    if (x[0] != s){ // startString present
        let y = x[1].componentsSeparatedByString(s2)
        if  (y[0] != x[1]) { // start and endString present
            returnedString = x[0]+y[1]
        } else { // startString present, endString missing
            returnedString = x[0]
        }
    } else { // startString missing
        let y = s.componentsSeparatedByString(s2)
        if  (y[0] != s)  { // no startString, endString present
            returnedString = y[1]
        } else { // no startString, endString missing
            returnedString = y[0]
        }
    }
    //println("returnedString: "+returnedString)
    return returnedString

}

func deleteAllEnclosedStrings (s: String, startString s1:String, endString s2:String) -> String{

    var returnedString = ""
    var allSubstrings = s.componentsSeparatedByString(s1)
    var strCount = allSubstrings.count
    for i in (0 ..< strCount) {
        var y = deleteEnclosedString(allSubstrings[i], s1 , s2)
        returnedString = returnedString + y
    }
    return(returnedString)
}

// test cases
// start and end available
deleteAllEnclosedStrings(str, startString: "[", endString: "]") // Hello, ground hi everybody
// start but no end
deleteAllEnclosedStrings(str, startString: "[", endString: "}") // Hello, play]ground again]hi everybody again] and
```

Comment: This is exactly what i'm looking for my friend. I appriciate for your help, thank you. But in this case, i need to change something on this code, because i tried it and it works well if i have only one start and end points. If i have multiple, it doesnt work. For example this string

var str = "Hello, [play]ground [again]hi everybody [again]"

when i run your code on this string, i get something like this = 
"Hello, ground"

but i have to clean up everything between '[' and ']' and i have to get this result = 
"Hello, ground hi everybody"

I hope i could explain myself better in this comment

Comment: solved it, than you ;)

Comment: I was in the middle of an update and may have over-written your response. Sorry. I am curious what your solution was.

Comment: `var startString = "["  
var endString = "]"  
   while (c.rangeOfString(startString) != nil){  
      var x = c.componentsSeparatedByString(startString)  
         if (x[0] != c){  
            var y = x[1].componentsSeparatedByString(endString)  
            c = c.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(y[0], withString:"") //delete inside of startString and endString  
            c = c.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(startString + endString, withString:"") //delete the startString and endString characters  
            }  
    }`  

PS: I still couldn't get used to this answer format :/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using `subStringWithRange`

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
var startIndex = 0
var endIndex = 18
str.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: str.startIndex, end: str.endIndex)) //"Hello, playground"
```

Then, you could assign that to a variable and do the rest. If you need further assistance let me know. Credit goes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044851/how-do-you-use-string-substringwithrange-or-how-do-ranges-work-in-swift). You can also have a look there for support.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you my friend :) My question is not well-explained because of my lask Reputation score, sorry about that. I was trying to ask if start and end indexes are not certain, it changes on every query.