# Understanding the removeRange(_:) documentation

Tags: swift

> To remove a substring at a specified range, use the removeRange(_:)
>   method:
>
> ```
> 1 let range = advance(welcome.endIndex, -6)..<welcome.endIndex
> 2 welcome.removeRange(range)
> 3 println(welcome)
> 4 // prints "hello"
> ```
>
> Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks.
>   https://itun.es/ca/jEUH0.l

Hi there,

I don't fully understand the syntax and the function of line 1 in the code above.

Please explain using this string:

```
let welcome = "hello there"
```

---

This is what I've worked out:

> "To change the start and end index, use `advance()`."
>   From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24045156/4839671

A better documentation of `advance()` is welcomed. i.e. it's arguments

> Use `..<` to make a range that omits its upper value
>
> Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/ca/jEUH0.l

`welcome.endIndex` will be 11

Comment: What is the difficulty? Strings have startIndex and endIndex. You must increase/decrease them via advance. A range is something like `<index>`...`<index>` or `index`..<`<index>`.

Comment: I was not aware that variables(or constants) can hold ranges.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Swift 2**

We're going to use `var` since `removeRange` needs to operate on a mutable string.

```
var welcome = "hello there"
```

This line:

```
let range = welcome.endIndex.advancedBy(-6)..<welcome.endIndex
```

means that we start from the end of the string (`welcome.endIndex`) and move back by 6 characters (advance by a negative number = move back), then ask for the range (`..<`) between our position and the end of the string (`welcome.endIndex`).

It creates a range of `5..<11`, which encompasses the *" there"* part of the string.

If you remove this *range of characters* from the string with:

```
welcome.removeRange(range)
```

then your string will be the remaining part:

```
print(welcome) // prints "hello"
```

You can take it the other way (from the start index of the string) for the same result:

```
welcome = "hello there"
let otherRange = welcome.startIndex.advancedBy(5)..<welcome.endIndex
welcome.removeRange(otherRange)
print(welcome) // prints "hello"
```

Here we start from the beginning of the string (`welcome.startIndex`), then we advance by 5 characters, then we make a range (`..<`) from here to the end of the string (`welcome.endIndex`).

*Note: the `advance` function can work forward and backward.*

**Swift 3**

The syntax has changed but the concepts are the same.

```
var welcome = "hello there"
let range = welcome.index(welcome.endIndex, offsetBy: -6)..<welcome.endIndex
welcome.removeSubrange(range)
print(welcome) // prints "hello"

welcome = "hello there"
let otherRange = welcome.index(welcome.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)..<welcome.endIndex
welcome.removeSubrange(otherRange)
print(welcome) // prints "hello"
```