# enumerateSubstringsInRange for line breaks and spaces

Tags: swift

I am looking to learn more about using **enumerateSubstringsInRange**. I want to take a text view and use it to create three arrays. one of the individual words. one of the sentences. and one of the intentional line breaks. I've seen how to do this only for sentences.

any references I could look at?

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start may be just checking out answers here on stackoverflow or apples documentation. Here is a good source  [How do you use String.substringWithRange? (or, how do Ranges work in Swift?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044851/how-do-you-use-string-substringwithrange-or-how-do-ranges-work-in-swift)