# New substring method swift 3

Tags: swift, substring

I'm not understanding how to extract a string in Swift 3, now I have this warning:

> 'init(start:end:)' is deprecated: it will be removed in Swift 3. Use the '..<' operator.

The code where this warning appear is the following:

```
labelReps.text = reps.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: reps.startIndex, end: reps.endIndex.advancedBy(-4)))
```

How can I translate that code in the new Swift 3 way?

Comment: `reps.substringWithRange(reps.startIndex ..< reps.endIndex.advancedBy(-4))`

Comment: Here is an extension that works like a charm in Swift 3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044851/how-do-you-use-string-substringwithrange-or-how-do-ranges-work-in-swift/39742687#39742687