# Take character from a specific position to last (swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift3

I have some string like **"Md. Monir-Uz-Zaman Monir"**, **"Md. Monir-Uz-Zaman Monir01"**, **"Md. Monir-Uz-Zaman Monir876"** .... Now I want to take a substring from **20th position** character to **last**. Actually I want output like **"Monir"**,**"Monir01"**, **"Monir876"**... The full string is not fixed but 1st 19 character is fixed.

I have done it in swift 2. But what would be answer for swift 3.

```
let nameString = str.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: str.startIndex.advancedBy(19), end: str.endIndex.advancedBy(0)))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does String substring work in Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677330/how-does-string-substring-work-in-swift-3)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use String.substringWithRange? (or, how do Ranges work in Swift?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044851/how-do-you-use-string-substringwithrange-or-how-do-ranges-work-in-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map(_:)` with array and then simply use `substring(from:)` with shorthand argument.

```
let strArray = ["Md. Monir-Uz-Zaman Monir", "Md. Monir-Uz-Zaman Monir01", "Md. Monir-Uz-Zaman Monir876"]
let nameArray = strArray.map { $0.substring(from: $0.index($0.startIndex, offsetBy: 19)) }
print(nameArray) //["Monir", "Monir01", "Monir876"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert string to array and get last object. Try below code

```
  let string : String = "Md. Monir-Uz-Zaman Monir"
  let fullNameArr = string.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
  print(fullNameArr[fullNameArr.count-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// swift 3
let input = "Md. Monir-Uz-Zaman Monir"
let start = input.index(input.startIndex, offsetBy: 19)
let required = input[start..<input.endIndex] // "Monir
```