# How to convert a Range<String> to a String in Swift

Tags: swift

Consider `dir` that is a `Range<String` :

```
let dir = url.absoluteString.range(of: "/", options: .backwards)
```

When trying to convert `dir` to a `String` via `String(dir)` we have:

```
Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Range<String.Index>?' conform to 'LosslessStringConvertible'
```

I have looked at a number of questions regarding `swift` substrings and `ranges` and have not found an exact answer to this.   So how can the  `Range` be converted to a `String`?

Comment: Can you show some sample inputs and outputs? Converting a `Range` to a `String` doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044851/how-do-you-use-string-substringwithrange-or-how-do-ranges-work-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

```
if let range = url.range(of: "/", options: .backwards) {
   let substr = url[range]
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this? The substring will always be equal to the search.

Comment: If you want to fetch the name of a file or a directory you don't need to reinvent the wheel. `url.lastPathComponent`

Comment: If you want the substring from the beginning to before /. It should be let substr = url[url.startIndex..<range.lowerBound]

Comment: @nghiahoang this is also pointless. `url.deletingLastPathComponent()`. If OP needs a string with the url scheme `url.deletingLastPathComponent().absoluteString` or without the scheme `url.deletingLastPathComponent().path`

Comment: this is not helping me. i would take back the upvote if possible

Comment: so if your url is `https://google.com` . What is value you want from String(dir)?

Comment: @LeoDabus  I'm tired of memorizing these strange library method names. I can't easily get autocompletion on them either.  Just a simple understanding of how to do  substrings and reverse find index etc.  PITA in swift it seems. I've tried using the   `s[start..<stop]` but that is also problematic.

Comment: you can use PartialRangeUpTo `string[..<index]`, PartialRangeThrough `string[...index]` or PartialRangeFrom `string[index...]`. But when working with URLs you should use the appropriate methods.

Comment: There is also the URLResourceValues you can use when dealing with fileURLs `if let name = (try? url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.nameKey]))?.name {`

Comment: I do agree about autocompletion is kind of sensitive. Try cleaning your project or testing it in  a new playground file.

Comment: I'm going to need some third party libraries to retain some fraction of my head. Looking at `swifterswift` . let's see. Yea it has subscript and slicing and slew of other conveniences.  So swift will be a language i don't use w/o additional tools. That's not the end of the world